# Polygons pours under BGAs?

Tags: layout, signal-integrity, bga

Is it a good practice to put polygon pours on the top layer underneath a BGA?

I've occasionally got several GND or VCC pins in a row/column, and I'd like to pour around them all.  I've got the same vias I would otherwise, this is just in my mind lowering the inductance between the pins and the vias.

The soldermask would then define the pad shapes.  Is that safe?

Is there any SI reason not to do this?  I can't think of a negative... it may even add a little more buried capacitance.

Is there any reason I shouldn't go nuts with pouring over everything?  (Being careful not to leave islands or little antenna structures)

I don't see this in the few reference designs I've checked...  so I'm curious why not...

EDIT:

Would this somehow prevent the ground plane from being as effective?  (If there's a large VCC pour between it and the BGA)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would not put a copper pour on the top layer of the PCB directly under a BGA.  Not because of any signal integrity issue, but because of a manufacturability issue.  There are two main reasons:

1. The increased copper could (and I emphasize the "could") suck too much heat away from the pads causing bad solder joints.
2. Normally the soldermask is pulled back a small amount from the pads.  If your copper plane had a direct connect to the pads (which it should) then the effective area for the pad would be increased.  And the increased pad size could cause solder issues where the amount of solder required for this ball is more than the solder required for a ball not connected to the plane.  The "unevenness" of the solder per ball could cause solder issues.

I'll be the first to admit that both issues could be solved by changing the oven temperature profile, changing the solder mask pullback, and/or changing the size or thickness of the solder paste screen.  But why?  Unless you have a very specific requirement (RF maybe), I don't see the advantage.  I've lost track of how many multi-GHz BGA's I've used and I have never needed a plane on the top layer of the PCB.

Comment: I'm evidently just going crazy trying to adequately decouple a very small BGA (0.8mm pitch, 4/4 trace space, 8/18 vias... the via annular ring is killing me) I have a couple caps with long-ish traces to the nearest via, and I'm trying to find a good way to compensate (by making the other caps as good as possible).  I'm very likely entirely overthinking it...

Comment: I'm trying very hard to avoid via-in-pad or microvias. I've just about got it but I'm very nervous about SI as I've never done DDR2 before. There are a lot of 'firsts' for this board for me.  It's right at the edge of my ability.

Comment: @darron  I have never had to use via-in-pad or microvias for a BGA before.  The vias I use have 10 mil holes and 22 mil pads.  This has worked fine for me with BGA's down to a 0.8 mm ball pitch.  Below that you need to either have a very creative fanout (works for smaller chips) or special vias.  Give me a part number and I'll see what I can come up with for how to route that part.

Comment: Freescale iMX283. It's a solid 17x17 grid. I guess vias are my main problem... (0.8mm - 18mil via) / 3 = ~4.5mil trace/space. I don't see how 22mil vias are possible.  Wouldn't that be (0.8mm - 22mil) / 3 = ~2mil trace/space?  Ho do you fit traces between vias?

Comment: @darron  Give me a day or two to work on the fanout of this part.  Besides, we're getting off topic for this question.  I'll figure out how to post the fanout when I'm done with it.

Comment: I'm using almost every pin. I'm not using the LCD interface, but that's all on an outside corner and so it doesn't help relieve the pressure much at all.  I managed to fit 18 0402 caps under the chip.  (out of 72 total)

Comment: I'd hate to see you waste much time on this...  but any general suggestion as to how to size vias and routing would be great. The best I can come up with is 4.5/4.5 routing with 8/18 vias like I said.  The recommended ball pad size for this part is 17mil.

Comment: Okay, I'm just worrying too much. I took a closer look at the reference design. It's been slightly useful before, but not nearly useful as it should be due to it's use of 8/16 vias. The decoupling on that looks insane to my eye and the board works. (They've got 5 decoupling caps tied lengthwise to a single via. Crazy)  I've probably been reading too much Howard Johnson and letting my idea of how close I have to get to the ideal he describes get out of hand.  Compared to this, my board should be fine.

Comment: @darron  I looked at a design we did here with 0.8mm pitch.  I was mistaken before.  We used an 8/16 via and a 16 mil BGA pad.  We use a larger via on our 1.0mm BGA's.  Putting caps under the BGAs is a good thing to do, and 18 of them sounds reasonable.  On some BGA's I can use cap arrays.  Howard Johnson is a good source, and sometimes paranoia can be a good thing.

Comment: 8/16 is a no-go for 4PCB, sierra proto express, and a few others I've checked and forgotten. 5 mil annular ring minimum (some say 6) It sure would have been nice though (the DDR2 routing could have been done in a single inner layer). I also ended up dropping some ports, and removing their corresponding vias meant I could get 6 more caps under the chip. I'm feeling a lot better about it in general now. I don't mind if something's wrong the first time... but my nightmare is spending $1800 on this board, it not working, and there being no obvious reason why not. :)

Comment: The docs say the footprint was optimized for "low cost 4 or 6 layer PCBs"...  only you have to use multiple expensive options to produce it (8 mil vias, 4/4 trace/space). 1mm pitch would have been SO much better. It'd be a 300 dollar prototype instead of 1800 dollars.